# Reflect changes in scope to current URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I'm quite new to angular and have no much front-end experience.
I use angular + material UI, and what'm trying to do is once user changed filter, those changes should be reflected to URL, e.g. suppose, user changed a value of an input field named "search_term" to be "foo", the URL should be example.com/search/?search_term=foo
So, I've got something like this:

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
    <label>Search term</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_term" ng-model="CTRL.search_term" required />
</md-input-container>
```

What I tried to do is:

```
$scope.$groupWatch(['search_term', 'duration', ... ], function (newValues, oldValues, scope)) {
    // assemble filter values, create query string, replace old query string with new one
    var qs = assembleNewQs();
    $location.search(qs);
}
```

And I realized this won't work due to that fact that `angular` overrides all of my watch's since I reference those variables in expressions.

I wouldn't like to do something like:

```
var currentQs = $location.search();
$timeout(function () {
    var newQs = assembleNewQs();
    if (currentQs != newQs) {
        $location.search(newQs);
        currentQs = newQs;
    }
}, 100);
```

This would work, of course, but is there any other, more clean, or, so to say, `angularish` way of doing that?

Comment: What are you using for routing?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire, nothing at all, it's exactly one view in my app, so why should I use something for routing?

Comment: The application itself is... well, you can think of it like google, so you've got a search box and results and once you type something in that search box, changes immediately appear as you type as well as query string should change so people are able to copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I would only change the URL on submit instead of on change...

The way to do it with routing would be:

```
$scope.submitSearch = function(query) {
  $state.go('search', {
    'search_term': query
  });
};
```

Set up the route:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('search', {
    url: '/search/?query',
    controller: 'SearchController',
    templateUrl: 'views/search.html'
});
```

- Don't forget to inject $stateProvider and add [ui.router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) to your project

Comment: That's not about updating the query string on submit. If I wanted the QS to be updated on submit, I wouldn't post this question at all since that's super-easy.

Comment: and why do I need any of those? I mean, stateProvider and ui.router? the only thing I need here, seems to be, `$location`, isn't it?

Comment: The whole idea behind this app is to be reactive and don't bother user with additional actions like pressing submit button

Comment: There doesn't necessarily have to be a submit button... I'm unclear what you're asking. I thought your question was `user changed a value of an input field named "search_term" to be "foo", the URL should be example.com/search/?search_term=foo` - my answer does exactly that

Comment: Then just do it in your watch function instead of $scope.submitSearch...